# Perform function on n rows from dataset

Tags: r

I have a dataset of 15480 data points. One variable is in %d/%m/%Y %H/%M form. I would like to group the data into groups of 180 and then find the mean of each of the associated variables for each group of 180 DateTimes. How would be best to do this without subsetting the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could assign an id to each row and calculate the mean by id. For example,

```
df$id <- rep(1:(15480/180),each=180)
aggregate(df$var,by=list(df$id),FUN=mean)
```

Comment: If this answer satisfies your question please indicate it with the check mark